# Shortcut is unavailable after migrating data from another computer and upgrading Windows

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

My computer with Windows XP on it crashed.  A technician copied pictures and videos from the hard drive to another computer with XP, then XP was updated to Windows 7 to mirror with the network system on a home group.

I would like to e-mail the videos but get error message:

> The drive or network connection that the shortcut (name of video) shortcut.Ink' refers to is unavailable.  Make sure that the disk is properly inserted on the network resources is available and try again.

There is no disk, the files are on the hard drive of the laptop.

Comment: Can you right-click the shortcut, select "Properties", and tell us what the shortcut points to? I'm afraid, as @JAvecesl said, just the shortcuts were copied, but not the actual files.

Answer (score 2):

I think Tech made a terrible mistake, didn´t copy the actual file but only a reference to it, and when Win 7 was installed the actual file dissapeared, sorry no way to recover since that disk was reformatted and rewritten